# Is this still an adapter pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, naming-conventions, naming, adapter

I stumbled upon this class and was wondering if XYZAdapter might be the correct name. I know how the adapter pattern works, but this solution is a bit different: Instead of implementing the DataTable interface and mapping the appropriate method calls, im creating a new DataTable object by copying the values and expose this object. Thats how it looks:

```
class Adapter
{
    private NodeList list;
    DataTable table { get { return CreateTable(); } }

    Adapter(NodeList nl)
    {
        list = nl;
    }

    private DataTable CreateTable()
    {
        // Fetch Data in NodeList, create a Table and return it
        // needs to be splitted in smaller methods ;D
    }
}
```

Usually im doing it this way, but the DataTable interface is enormus:

```
class Adapter : DataTable
{
    private NodeList list;
    DataTable table { get { return CreateTable(); } }

    Adapter(NodeList nl)
    {
        list = nl;
    }
    // Here are all the DataTable methods mapped to NodeList
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the code solve the problem you are trying to solve? Is it bug free and maintainable? If so why do you care if it uses a particular design pattern?

Comment: What is the question? Whether what you're doing can be called by some name?

Comment: @Ben Because i want to know and learn. I wont change any implementation only if its not a known pattern. But i might change the name of the class from XYZAdapter to XYZConverter/Translator for readability reasons.
@chris yep thats at least a part of my question. I stumbled upon this class and was wondering if XYZAdapter might be the correct name.

Comment: I was wondering why myself :) Naming is important.. I'd mimic the WPF convention for ValueConverters and name it as NodeListToDataTableConverter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An adapter adapts a non-compliant interface into a compliant one. e.g. it transforms/wraps a circular peg to form a square peg, so that it fits a square slot.

Your solution is not technically the adapter pattern - it's more of a translator or a converter. The key difference being that your adapter cannot be substituted in methods expecting an instance of a DataTable.